# addthis button default message

Tags: javascript, addthis

How to set default message, I am using addthis button for invite a friend Email on a website. that default message should also work if user choose gmail, yahoo etc from addthis box.

Comment: This may be better off on [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com)

Comment: What do you have so far? I was unaware that addthis has that detailed level of functionality regarding email.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use their [email templates](http://www.addthis.com/help/email-templates).