# addthis button default message

Tags: addthis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [addthis button default message](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4424/addthis-button-default-message)

How to set default message, I am using addthis button for invite a friend Email on a website. that default message should also work if user choose gmail, yahoo etc from addthis box.

Comment: your question is better suited for webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

This sounds really similar to this post which was also asked 2 days ago:

http://www.addthis.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=26910&view=next

From the sounds of it you're trying to configure the AddThis button to let you dynamically change the message sent to the user. This opens up a world of spam problems if your button is abused.